# Javascript if a dropdown button is selected, textboxes must change color

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hi I have a simple question.
I want to change the textbox color when a dropdown button is selected to "Future". This is what I have tried so far. There are no errors and if I put the `$('[name="strike"]').css("background-color", "red");` line in the console then the textbox goes red. So I assume there is something wrong with the if condition ?

```
if ($('[name="putCallButton"]').text() == "Future"){
  $('[name="strike"]').css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: `if($("#someId option:selected").text() == "Future") ..`

Comment: I work with Vue.js so don't have an ID just name

Comment: need to add the `vue.js` tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

use on event :

```
$('[name="putCallButton"]').on("select", function() {
  if ($('[name="putCallButton"]').text() == "Future"){
    $('[name="strike"]').css("background-color", "red");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the value attribute to your option tag and set its value same as the option text.

```
$('[name="putCallButton"]').on('change', function() {
 if ($('[name="putCallButton"]').val() == "Future"){
  $('[name="strike"]').css("background-color", "red");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.value()` instead of `.text()`. `.text()` returns all the options of the selected item